# Intercept keypress and change focus in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of `div.boxinput` (each with two input fields). If a key like down arrow is pressed, I need to change focus of other input.

I can intercept the key, but I cannot move the focus to another input.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
         alert("down"); 

          // find where is the focus ? 
           var hasFocus = $('input').is(':focus');
           alert(hasFocus);


         // change focus ( problem here, don't change focus )
         if ( $(hasFocus).parent().hasClass("reso") ) {
             $(hasFocus).parent().prev().find("input").focus();
          }else{
             $(hasFocus).parent().next().find("input").focus();
          }

      }     

       if (e.keyCode == 37) { alert("left"); }
       if (e.keyCode == 38) { alert("top"); }
       if (e.keyCode == 39) { alert("right"); }
});
```

I create my experiment here: [jsfiddle.net/andreaferri/mt95g9cu/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/andreaferri/mt95g9cu/7/)

How do I select the item that has focus?

Comment: First of all $('input').is(':focus'); returns True and not the object, so when you are using the hasFocus in $(hasFocus).parent().hasClass("reso") it cant find the element because you are passing just True

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

You're right, how can I make me return the object that has focus?
So 'I can use .parent () to put the focus on another item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is working script that changes focus.

```
var focused;
$('input').focus(function() {
          focused = $(this);
}); 
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       if ( $(focused).parent().hasClass("reso") ) {
          $(focused).parent().prev().find("input").focus();
       } else {
          $(focused).parent().next().find("input").focus();
       }
    }               
});
```

As you see you have to get object like this (This is the part where i set focused input you see?) :

```
var focused;
$('input').focus(function() {
   focused = $(this);
});
```

As i promised you here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukpho7ua/). Again this is just a suggestion how to get it done, its not full for all the keys. It works just for key down and it switches then only left to right or right to left input in any row that you are focused on. Try it and let me know if you got any more questions, but this is the answer on your question how to change the focus on elements when the key is pressed. I think you get the idea how it works now and how to change focus.

Comment: Hi, thankx for your answer, but this code don't work! Where your get che element that have focus now ? You use "focused" but you don't do the assigment.... or not?

Comment: I do use the assignment here : 
$('input').focus(function() {
      focused = $(this);
    }); 
i will put it into js fiddle to show you that it works ok? Did you replace your code with what i have posted in my answer?

Comment: I edited my answer and provided jsFiddle example. Check it out and if it helped you, check the answer as right. If you have any more questions just ask :-)